# Right way validate TextFormField in Form widget

Tags: dart, flutter

Instead of write separate validate method of each `TextFormField` is there any way to be managed by single method like below.

```
String _isValidatedField(String strInputText) {
    String pEmailChk =
        r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';

    if (_conFirstName.text.isEmpty) {
      return 'Please enter first name';
    } else if (_conLastName.text.isEmpty) {
      return 'Please enter last name';
    } else if (_conUserName.text.isEmpty) {
      return 'Please enter username';
    } else if (_conEmailName.text.isEmpty) {
      return 'Please enter email address';
    } else if (RegExp(pEmailChk).hasMatch(_conEmailName.text) == false) {
      return 'Please enter valid email addres';
    }
    else if (_conEmailName.text.length != 10) {
      return 'Please enter valid phone number';
    }

    return null;
  }
```

Problem is When any validation will fail then error will be occurred for each `TextFormField` rather than error should be display on particular `TextFormField` that was fail.

Answer (score 0):

TextformField has a validator parameter through which you can validate particular text form field

```
TextFormField(
        key: new Key('email'),
        decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
        autocorrect: false,
        validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'Email can\'t be empty.' : null,
        onSaved: (val) => _email = val,
      )
```

Comment: I know that but if I want to use same method (As mentioned in my Que.) for all validator method of all TextFormField, Then how can I achieve it? Is it possible or we have to declare separate validator method for each TextFormField?